# Possible to link Gmail labels to Google Drive folders?

Tags: gmail, google-drive-api, directory, label

By setting up Gmail labels to match Google Drive folders (e.g. `My Work-->Recent` in Gmail labels has matching folders in Google Drive), I can organize both together and not get disorganized.

### The problem being, every time I make a change to the label/add a label in Gmail, I have to go into Google Drive to match the change (and visa versa).

Is it possible that a change to a label or folder is mirrored automatically in the other application, through Google App Scripts?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: I'm not really a programmer so just wondering if it's possible? I would then try doing it but not sure if it's realistic goal?